# Create Custom category Yes/No attribute magento2

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute

Is it possible to create the custom attribute for a category called `is_featuted` category as 'Yes/No' attribute?

I am looking for code how to create the custom attribute for category and get all the categories where the attribute value is `'Yes'`.

Can we get all the category collection where is_featured is `"Yes"`?

Here is the code i used in InstallData.php

```
 <?php

 namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

 use Magento\Framework\Setup\{
 ModuleContextInterface,
 ModuleDataSetupInterface,
  InstallDataInterface
};

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'is_featured', [
        'type'     => 'int',
        'label'    => 'Is Home Category',
        'input'    => 'boolean',
        'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
        'visible'  => true,
        'default'  => '0',
        'required' => false,
        'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group'    => 'Display Settings',
      ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'is_featured',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Is Home Category',
                'input' => 'select',
                'sort_order' => 333,
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <fieldset name="general">
            <field name="is_featured">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Is Home Category</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: hi, @Hassan It is showing in admin now, but as a textbox not as yes/no, i created yes/no attribute through InstallData

Comment: you need dropdown ?

Comment: yes, dropdown or switcher

Comment: updated my answer added:  <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean</item>

Comment: No, still it is showing as textbox. flushed cache and checked

Comment: I cnanged this line to  <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>, now dropdown coming but Default value shoud be No, now it is selected with Yes

Comment: I forget to update Setup/InstallData.php update it as well. Need to re-install

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85534/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-hassan-ali-shahzad).

Comment: hi, @Hassan, attribute is created but as a textbox, not the select element. pls check once.

Comment: I am able to bring select element now, but default value should be No, now it is selected as 'Yes'

Answer (score 10):

Add Following Code in ui_component xml file to Add Yes/No Toggle Option in Your admin Category Attribute. 
File Path :view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
<field name="your_attribute" sortOrder="100" formElement="checkbox">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Your Attriute</label>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <checkbox>
                    <settings>
                        <valueMap>
                            <map name="false" xsi:type="string">0</map>
                            <map name="true" xsi:type="string">1</map>
                        </valueMap>
                        <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                    </settings>
                </checkbox>
            </formElements>
        </field>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: this is the correct answer for the yes/no toggle

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below tutorial. It will add boolean custom attribute to category.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html

Change

```
 'label'    => 'Your Category Attribute Name',
```

to your required label like

```
 'label'    => 'Is Featured',
```

To filter category collection by this custom attribute, you can use below code.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;

protected $collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
 .....
 $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
 .....
}

$categories =   $this->collectionFactory->create()
  ->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured',1)->load();
```

Comment: can i use this code for existing module? please update me code of InstallData.php

Comment: In my given link, there is already InstallData.php file.

Comment: where to add the attribute code? 
$eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'is_featured', [ ?

Comment: I have used your code, but attribute is not created for categories? I have posted my InstallData.php file to question

Comment: Its created now, but i can't see it in admin panel inside category view

Comment: hi, @Kishan , i can see my custom attribute is created and show in database, but why it is not showing in category view page?

Comment: need to add input=>select 
&
source their as well

Comment: Its not worked for me, attribute is created but collection is not returned.

Comment: @jafarpinjar what do you mean by not returned ?

Comment: $categories =   $this->collectionFactory->create()
  ->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured',1)->load(); this is not returned anything for me